# Shared data in python Multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, shared-memory

I have this script thats recording audio, generating a spectogram, saving it, comparing it with a previously trained model and then giving a prediction. Based on the prediction i want the mouse to move on the direction that was said. The script was working with Threading but not with Multiprocessing and i guess its because the variables is_moving and movement_direction are not being update since the move_mouse() function is running inside a Process. I'm having a really hard time trying to understand shared variables and data on Multiprocessing and i was hoping somebody could help me out

Thanks in advance

This is my code as of right now

```
import pyautogui
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sys import byteorder
import librosa
import librosa.display
import tensorflow as tf
from array import array
import numpy as np
import pyaudio
import sys
from keras.models import load_model
from PIL import Image
import threading
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import multiprocessing

model = keras.models.load_model(r'ModeloFinal.h5')

MOVEMENT_SPEED = 10

np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)
img_height = int(480/2) #432 #28
img_width = int(640/2)


class AudioRecorder:
    def __init__(self):
        self.rate = 44100
        self.threshold = 0.018 # silence threshold {Need to experiment with it}
        self.chunk_size = 1024
        self.format = pyaudio.paFloat32
        self._pyaudio = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    def isSilent(self, data):
        # Returns true if below the silence threshold
        return max(data) < self.threshold

    def trim(self, data):
        # Trim the blanks at the start and end
        def _trim(data):
            started = False
            r = array('f')
            for i in data:
                if not started and abs(i) > self.threshold:
                    started = True
                    r.append(i)
                elif started:
                    r.append(i)
            return r

        # First trim the left side
        data = _trim(data)
        data.reverse()

        # Then trim the right side
        data = _trim(data)
        data.reverse()

        return data

    def addSilence(self, data):
        # Adds silence to the start and end of 0.1 seconds
        r = array('f', [0 for i in range(int(0.1 * self.rate))])
        r.extend(data)
        r.extend([0 for i in range(int(0.1 * self.rate))])

        return r

    def record(self):
        stream = self._pyaudio.open(format=self.format, channels=1, rate=self.rate, input=True, output=True, frames_per_buffer=self.chunk_size)
        numSilent = 0
        started = False
        r = array('f')

        while True:
            # Has to be little endian and signed short
            data = array('f', stream.read(self.chunk_size))

            if byteorder == 'big':
                data.byteswap()

            r.extend(data)
            silent = self.isSilent(data)

            if silent and started:
                numSilent += 1
            elif not silent and not started:
                started = True
                print('Noise detected, recording beginning')
            if started and numSilent > 20:  # If there are 30 silences, break (doesn't handle long sentences).
                break

        stream.stop_stream()
        stream.close()

        r = self.trim(r)
        r = self.addSilence(r)

        r = np.array(r, dtype=np.float32)

        fig, ax = plt.subplots()

        melspec = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=r, sr=self.rate, n_mels=256, fmax=22000, hop_length=8)
        norm_melspec = librosa.core.power_to_db(melspec, ref=np.max)
        img = librosa.display.specshow(norm_melspec, x_axis='time', y_axis='mel', sr=self.rate, fmax=22000, ax=ax)
        plt.savefig(('spokenWord.png'), transparent=True)
        plt.close()

        imgToPredict = Image.open('spokenWord.png').convert('RGB')
        imgToPredict = imgToPredict.resize((img_width, img_height))
        im_np = np.asarray(imgToPredict)
        print(np.shape(im_np))
        numpydata = im_np.reshape(1, img_height, img_width, 3)
        predictions = model.predict(numpydata)
        pred_labels = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)
        print("Result")
        print(pred_labels)

        if pred_labels[0] == 0:
            mouse_controller.move_up()
        elif pred_labels[0] == 1:
            mouse_controller.move_down()
        elif pred_labels[0] == 2:
            mouse_controller.move_left()
        elif pred_labels[0] == 3:
            mouse_controller.move_right()
        elif pred_labels[0] == 4:
            mouse_controller.pause_movement()
        else:
            mouse_controller.click_mouse()

        print('Returning to listening')

        if silent:
            self.record()

    def listen(self):
        print('Listening beginning')
        self.record()


class MouseController:
    is_moving = False
    movement_direction = None

    def move_mouse(self):
        if self.is_moving:
            print('abc')
            if self.movement_direction == 'up':
                pyautogui.move(0, -MOVEMENT_SPEED)
            elif self.movement_direction == 'down':
                pyautogui.move(0, MOVEMENT_SPEED)
            elif self.movement_direction == 'left':
                pyautogui.move(-MOVEMENT_SPEED, 0)
            elif self.movement_direction == 'right':
                pyautogui.move(MOVEMENT_SPEED, 0)

    def move_up(self):
        print('UP')
        if not self.is_moving:
            self.is_moving = True
            self.movement_direction = 'up'

    def move_down(self):
        print('DOWN')
        if not self.is_moving:
            self.is_moving = True
            self.movement_direction = 'down'

    def move_left(self):
        print('LEFT')
        if not self.is_moving:
            self.is_moving = True
            self.movement_direction = 'left'

    def move_right(self):
        print('RIGHT')
        if not self.is_moving:
            self.is_moving = True
            self.movement_direction = 'right'

    def click_mouse(self):
        self.is_moving = False
        pyautogui.click()

    def pause_movement(self):
        self.is_moving = False


a = AudioRecorder()
mouse_controller = MouseController()


def audio_thread():
    a.listen()


def mouse_thread():
    while True:
        mouse_controller.move_mouse()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    audio_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=audio_thread)
    mouse_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=mouse_thread)

    audio_process.start()
    mouse_process.start()

    audio_process.join()
    mouse_process.join()
```

Comment: the processes in multiprocessing are independent of each other so you cannot share in the normal way.

Comment: You might want to look into shared memory. It's non-trivial

Comment: you also have the option to read and write from disk (slow but convenient) or in memory database like sqlite (slightly better).